# Show value from last day of the given month - SSRS Report Builder

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

In a Report Builder table I have to show the value from the last day of the given month, when the month is not expanded.
When the month is expanded, the dates have to show the specific value for that day.
Example is January with values 1 to 31 (same as the day numbers):

- When January is expanded, it has to show value 1 on Jan 1.... value 15 on Jan 15... value 31 on Jan 31.
- When contracted (and the table only show one row for January), it should show the last day's value of 31
- Some months do not have values on all days, so the formula just need to take the last value of that given month

When I use the formula "Last()", then it works half of the time, while for some months, the value extracted is the 3rd or 4th last day of the month - do you know what is wrong here?

Hope above makes sense, and thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it my self:

- Using Last () formula
- Learning how to make a sort order in my Union All dataset, so it came out in the right way

How to give points to my self?

Comment: or you could just use MAX() and then you don't have to order your dataset.

Comment: Hi, first I used MAX(), but that only gave me the max of the month instead of the value on the last day. Or perhaps I am misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: I would need to see what your dataset looks like, a sample of the data, but it should be simple to do using MAX() as long as the expression is in the correct scope. As you have a solution you might not want to pursue this but if you want me to take a look, post a sample of you dataset and the expected output.